# iphone - how do i check if NSMutableArray ObjectAtIndex doesnt have any value

Tags: iphone

how do i check an array if objectatIndex has any values? im using a forloop

```
for (i = 0; i < 6 ; i++)
{
    if ([array objectAtIndex: i] == NULL)//This doesnt work.
    {
        NSLog(@"array objectAtIndex has no data");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't store `nil` in a Foundation collection class such as `NSArray`, you have to use `NSNull`. To check to see if a member of the array is `NSNull`, you would do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i ++) {
    if ([array objectAtIndex:i] == [NSNull null]) {
        NSLog(@"object at index %i has no data", i);
    }
}
```

If you want to see how many items are in the array, use `-[NSArray count]`. If you want to iterate through the array to see if *any* object is `NSNull`, but you don't care which one, you could use fast enumeration or `-[NSArray containsObject:]`:

```
for (id anObject in array) {
    if (anObject == [NSNull null]) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

or

```
if ([array containsObject:[NSNull null]]) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the condition

```
if ([[Array objectAtIndex:i] length] == 0) {
// Do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have nil values in a `NSArray` (or `NSMutableArray`). So your `if` clause will never return true. Also, you should use `nil` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: `nil` and `NULL` are the same thing.  *By convention* we use `nil` for object pointers and `NULL` for everything else, but it's just convention.  There is no difference between the two.  (You can verify this by cmd-double clicking on a `nil` and seeing what it's defined as)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what @Marco said: you're guaranteed that `objectAtIndex:` will never return `nil` unless something goes horrifically wrong.  However, by the time you get to that point, it's too late anyway and there's nothing you can do about (and you're more likely to get an exception thrown before this every happens).

If you need to store a value to indicate "there's nothing here", you should use the `[NSNull null]` singleton.  This is *exactly* what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

As far I know-
There is no index without an object. because when you remove an object, the array will trimmed by itself. You can put some empty object like @"" or NSNull, but that an object at least.

Another point, you will get [NSRangeException](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSRangeException) if the index you are looking for is out of bound.